# JavaFX - ListView ScrollBar EventFilter and scrollToTop

Tags: listview, events, javafx, scrollbar

I have an EventFilter, in my CustomList, to force selection rather than scrolling, and need to position the ScrollBar on top after listView has loaded. But when the method scrollToTop is execute after loading, the ScrollBar does not move anymore and stay on top.

The EventFilter:

```
private final EventHandler<ScrollEvent> scrollEventFilter = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(ScrollEvent t) {
    if (t.getDeltaY() < 0) {
        getSelectionModel().selectNext();
    } else {
        getSelectionModel().selectPrevious();
    }

    t.consume();
  }
};
```

The scrollToTop method:

```
public void scrollToTop() {
  Node n = lookup(".scroll-bar");
  if (n instanceof ScrollBar) {
    final ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) n;
    if (bar.getOrientation().equals(Orientation.VERTICAL)) {
        bar.setValue(0.5);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your partial codes;

1) Since the default max and min values of scrollbar are 1.0 and 0.0 respectively, the scrollToTop method is not scrolling to top. Because you are setting the scrollbar's value to 0.5 in it, which means "scroll to center" of the loaded ListView.

2) After attaching the eventHandler, the scrollbar will not move any more, because the event handler consuming the `ScrollEvent`. The scrollBar will not move by mouse wheel, but it will scroll by mouse drag on it.

3) I suggest to use `ListView.scrollTo()` method as:

```
private final EventHandler<ScrollEvent> scrollEventFilter = new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
@Override
public void handle(ScrollEvent t) {
    if (t.getDeltaY() < 0) {
        getSelectionModel().selectNext();
    } else {
        getSelectionModel().selectPrevious();
    }

    scrollTo(lst.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());

    t.consume();
  }
```

};